# Global modifier not working in variable scope of a function

Tags: php

I have code that looks something like this

```
<?php
    $a = "text";

    function hay() {
        global $a;
        return $a;
    }

    $b = hay();
    var_dump($b); // outputs NULL
?>
```

It doesn't display any errors.
The global modifier just doesn't work.

Comment: Your missing a `;` after `return $a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scope is not global. I think that your file included inside some fumction. That's why variable `$a` is not global. You could add global keyword to globalize your variable.

```
global $a;
$a = "text";
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a semicolon in return `return $a`. This should be `return $a;`. Try this and your code will work

Comment: That was just a typo ;)